# Concerned that listing "other" may mislead when displaying ranges

Tags: forms, wizard, multi-step, range

In the image below, you can see below the blue line 4 options. I am creating a step by step wizard where I try to minimize the amount of user typing required by adding in clickable buttons to collect preset data. In this step, I want to get a range from users. The most common ones our business deals with are the 3 you see. We have about 20 other ranges that we offer, however it would be way too much to put on the page, so we elected to add an "other" option. If they click on other, the contents above the blue line would then appear instead of the contents on the bottom of the line, allowing the user to enter their own range.

The question we are debating internally is, 1, should we just start with the enter your own range, 2, just make the "other" be 100+ (which I don't like because their custom range may be 40-50) or change the label on "other" to be something more descriptive like "custom range"

Additionally, not sure if I should go for a thicker stroke, or a different stroke color/font weight for the unselected boxes. Selected boxes would be red with white bold text.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Personal opinion, but I agree that `Other` or `Custom` is preferable to `100+`.

This may be a case where you can keep the default ranges and use something like a [range slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range) for your custom input.

Here the user clicks/presses on the `1 - 25` range, then on the `Other` button which animates a change in the control. The range box on the left could accept keyboard input if you want.

[image]

[view full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZOMy.jpg)

Comment: I appreciate the response, I had not considered a slider yet, solid alternative for sure